# Changing an array in a reducer when an item has been deleted or updated in react/redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I am using react/redux and have been looking at ways to update my array of posts in my reducer if a post is edited or deleted.

Is there a more simple way rather than doing something with creating an `index` function which finds the index of the post you are trying to delete/update, then returning the current state with the updated array using slice?

This is what I have so far in my reducer, I am kind of stuck:

```
import constants from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  all: [],
  sorted: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.CREATE_OFFER:
      newState[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      newState.all.unshift(action.payload);
      return newState;

    case constants.GET_OFFERS:
      newState.all = action.payload;
      return newState;

    case constants.GET_OFFER:
      newState[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      return newState;

    case constants.EDIT_OFFER:
      newState[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      return newState;

    case constants.DELETE_OFFER:
      newState[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      return newState;

    case constants.SORT_OFFERS:
      newState.sorted = action.payload;
      return newState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Remember to make `EDIT_OFFER` and `DELETE_OFFER` edit / remove the corresponding offers.  Also `sorted` is an array in `initialState` and an offer in `SORT_OFFERS`  (I guess you haven't implemented that yet?)

Comment: Correct @AJP I will implement that later, I think I got the answer below though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, everything is good, but it will be better to use es6 spread operator, your code will look more clear

```
case constants.CREATE_OFFER:
   return {
     ...state,
     all: state.all.concat(action.payload),
    [action.payload.id]: action.payload 
   }

case constants.EDIT_OFFER:
   return {
     ...state,
    [action.payload.id]: action.payload,
    all: state.all.map( item => item.id === action.payload.id?action.payload: item ) 
   }

case constants.DELETE_OFFER:
   const new = {
     ...state,
     all: state.all.filter( item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
   };
   delete new[action.payload.id];

   return new;
 }
```

Comment: For edit offers how do I change the all state, I dont think you included that

Comment: I am getting error of `unexpected token` on the `return {...state}`, it points to the first `.`

Comment: you should check that you have support for spread operator - http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
newState[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
      return newState;
```

You can use ES6 sytax :

```
return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload.data};
```

i believe if you use Object as a app state rather than an array , it will be easy to update , delete all you need to do is use .mapKeys method of lodash library along with property you want to extract from your array (ideally 'id')

```
import _ from 'lodash';
return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');
```

this will return :

```
{
  '1': { id: 1,
    title: 'Hello!',
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2,
    title: 'World'
  }
}
```

You can read more [Here](https://lodash.com/docs/#mapKeys)

Comment: const newState = Object.assign({}, state);